# how to move all files and folders to another folder using mv command

Tags: linux, terminal, mv, putty

how can I move files and folders from a folder to another directory? I am using mv and my files is in a subfolder. do I have to use ../ to specify the path?

I use `cd /` to go to the root. my folder is in root(after cd /) > backup > folderwithfiles, and I want to transfer it to  root > live > newfolder.

how can I achieve this using mv? I tried `mv -v ~/Downloads/* ~/Videos/` but I know it will not work since the syntax is for same level folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your files are currently in /backup/folderwithfiles and you want to move folderwithfiles to /live/newfolder then:

```
   cd /backup
   mv folderwithfiles /live/newfolder
```

If newfolder already existed, your files will then be in:

```
   /live/newfolder/folderwithfiles
```

If newfolder did not already exist, then your files would be in:

```
   /live/newfolder
```

If you just want to move the files that are in folderwithfiles but not move the entire directory, then:

```
   mv folderwithfiles/* /live/newfolder
```

In which case newfolder must already exist.

The example mv you posted should have moved the files from the Downloads directory into the Video directory, but not move the Downloads directory itself.

Comment: thanks for this one!